# How to add or remove users from a Discord server via the API

Tags: discord

I am selling a SaaS product that comes with a Discord server for users. This is a renewal product, so if the user's license expires then I would like to remove them from the server.

How can I achieve this? What input will they need to give me? Is it best to have a login with discord button on my website or should I just have them give me their username then I can send them an invite link when they register, and remove them if their license expires using the API. What if they change their username?

I have done my best to figure out how to achieve both of these approaches by reading https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro, but I feel their documentation is seriously lacking and it is difficult to find what I need.

EDIT: It would also be useful to be able to generate one time only invite links. Once the user clicks the link, their discord user ID is sent to me so I can add it into the database. Then, say every day, I scan the database for expired users and if that user has expired then I invoke `kick` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.kick. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the many discord libraries like `discord.js` and `discord.py`?

Comment: @Aplet123 I have linked the discord.py docs... I just can't figure out how to do what I described.

Answer (score 0):

you get their discord id as soon as they join the discord server by using

````
client.on('guildmemberadd', (member) {
console.log(member.id)
{```

from there you can hook in your database and simply create a entry containing their 
member.id member.username and whatever else you require by a join date Date.now()
````

Comment: im sorry i just noticed you are using discordpy this is a discord.js resolution

Comment: How do I link their email address to their user ID though?

Comment: you could create a !link command and have them link it for example !link test@test.com and then send the data to your database